# Apply class on element inside ng-container with [ngTemplateOutlet]

Tags: angular

I have a PARENT component which has a CHILD component.
This PARENT component holds `ng-template` which will be bound into the CHILD component.

In order to `style` the `ng-container`'s element (`svg`), I used `ng-deep` and it worked.

What I want now is to dynamically add a `class` to the `ng-container`'s element (`svg`) from the CHILD component (like `ngClass`);

Please see my code below for better understading.

### PARENT

HTML:

```html
...

<app-input [icon]="userIcon"></app-input>

...

<!-- TEMPLATES -->

<ng-template #userIcon>
    <svg>...</svg>
</ng-template>
```

---

### CHILD

HTML:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="$icon" [ngTemplateOutlet]="$icon"></ng-container>

...
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```js
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  ...

  @Input('icon') public $icon: TemplateRef<any>;
  private color: boolean = false; // --> When this is true, apply a new class

  public onFocus(): void {
    this.color = true;
  }

  ...
```

SCSS:

```css
::ng-deep {
    svg {
        transition: .3s fill;
        fill: map-get($colors, placeholder);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't style `ng-container` as it does not exist as `HTMLElement` at runtime. You actually like to add a class to the `svg` element created from the template, which replaces the `ng-container` (see "Content Projection in Angular").

Answer (score 1):

with ng-container you can pass context like

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="user;context: {color: className}></ng-container>
```

then you can use it like in template

```
<ng-template let-color="color">
    <div [class]="color"></div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not wish to pass it from the PARENT component, but to dynamically add it from the CHILD.